# Can't print on Ubuntu 16.04 with Epson L210

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

Even yesterday I printed with my Epson L210 printer on Ubuntu 16.04 and after shutdown - today - it does not work. Firstly, there was written, that printer filter was not found, so I reinstalled cups and printer driver. Still not working, but it don't show error with printer filter. When I click 'Print', it adds print job to the Completed and nothing happens. If you know what's the problem, help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lsb/+bug/1536353

I had a similar problem with my Brother DCP-J152W printer. Basically install the LSB printer package. While the launchpad item indicates it is fixed it is still not installed in my 16.04LTS updated daily, as of today 10/08/16 (UK/rest of world date format.) 
I chose the easier way, if you are not happy with using the terminal, it is easy to use the Synaptic Package Manager. If you do not have this already you can install it from the Ubuntu Software Centre (the orange suitcase with "A" on it. 
Once you have Synaptic open it and click the spyglass "search" icon and type lsb. Scroll down to lsb-printing and click then select "Mark for Installation" then click "Apply" at the top and then "Apply" again in the lower right of the box. Then close Snaptic. 
Then re-install your printer driver. Or check, it may even work without re-installing. 
I had been searching for several days for the answer to this and ended up transferring the document on a SD card to my netbook which still has 14.04LTS on it which did include the LSB package as standard.

UPDATE:
While adding LSB seemed to fix the problem initially it has only lasted until I have re-booted. However I have also changer routers and re-set the wlan setup on the printer accordingly.

So problem still exists with all listed LSB (in Synaptic) modules installed. 
Printer "name of printer queue" may not be connected. Though it is shown connected and active in my router listings.